# Macro that calls different function based on parameter

Tags: c++, macros

Hello all I was having trouble with macros so I thought I would practice and I was looking at the ## macro operator and thought I could use it for my problem I wan't to be able to call multiple functions based on the parameter for example if I have a macro like so:

```
#define macro(a) func##a();


int main()
{

   .....
   for(int i = 0;i< length;i++)
   {
      macro(i)

   }



func1()
{



}
....
func31()
{


}
```

Anyone have an idea of how I can accomplish this??

Comment: This isn't even real code. Please give us a minimal reproducible example that highlights the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: The macro expansion takes place at compile time and not at runtime

Comment: @Christophe Preprocessing happens before compilation.

Comment: @0x499602D2 true, but my point was compile time vs. runtime meaning that the macro will deal with i and not with its value. I didn't want to go in the difference btw preprocessing, parsing, code genaration and linking.

Comment: @Christophe So why didn't you just say it takes place before runtime? That would have been equally as accurate.

Comment: Ok :-)  `#define COMPILE_TIME (period_between_the_moment_you_invoque _compiler_front_end && moment_you_can_use_its_output)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only combine two preprocessor tokens. However, `func` isn't a preprocessor token. You need to jump through an extra hoop, calling some form of "concat" macro:

```
#define CONCAT(a, b) a ## b
#define macro(a) CONCAT(func,a)
```

Of course, the tokens produced by you macro won't be `func1`, ..., `func31` (of course, they would also need to start with `func0` if your logic were correct) but rather `funci`. The expansion of macros happens at the beginning of compilation while the execution of the `for`-loop happens at run-time (some optimizations may hoist it into compile-time but that won't affect the macros).

If you need to expand a sequence of integers in combination with a macro, you may want to have a look at the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) preprocessor library, in particular at the `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` functionality.

If you just need to statically expand a sequence of integers to function calls, you might also consider looking at function template templatized on an integers: I would certainly consider using an approach using templates before trying to use the preprocessor library...

Comment: So I wouldn't be able to do what I am trying to accomplish with a macro since it is a preproccessor directive?

Comment: Clearly, the preprocessor replaces tokens long before run-time: it is nearly the first step in the process compiling a C or C++ file. The loop isn't even executed at compile-time at all but rather at run-time.

Comment: I'm adding my answer as a comment here since it might be more complete: What you're trying to do is not possible because the i variable (except optimizations) is incremented at runtime. Macro preprocessing is a before-compile passage and it's entirely text-based.

There's no way to get the preprocessor to actually execute your code and figure out which tokens are to be expanded and generate the functions to call.

Comment: @MarcoA., Depends on your definition of not possible. one could use `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` to generate N function calls.

Comment: @MarcoA. Is it possible to do this without a macro or is it all together just not possible

Comment: @chris It's somewhat different from what the user asked though

Comment: @AnonymousUser Off the top of my head I would implement the whole stuff differently if you need to call a number of functions at runtime, anyway there might be ways that I can't see right now on how to accomplish your goal